# How to make Parse data columns "hidden"?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Is there a way to make certain data stored on Parse.com hidden to admins like the password fields are?

I want to hide certains columns from view in a class. Thanks in advance

Comment: save encrypted data on parse and decrypt while using in App.

Comment: Read about the roles in parse that might help you out in giving access to info (columns) to a specific user.

Comment: Who are admins and how are they accessing the data? Who are other users and how...